Getting error: RPC server unavailable while trying to read outlook email through Python
I am getting the error as (-2147023174, 'The RPC server is unavailable.', None, None)
I am trying the below code:
import win32com.client
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
outputDir = 'C:/Users/Sources/Output'
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
for account in mapi.Accounts:
    print(account.DeliveryStore.DisplayName)
inbox=outlook.Folders("mail@outlook.com").Folders("Inbox")
messages = inbox.Items
email_sender = 'sender@outlook.com'
received_dt = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=3)
received_dt = received_dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')
messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '"+received_dt+"'")
try:
    for message in list(messages):
        if message.SenderEmailAddress == email_sender:
            try:
                s = message.sender
                for attachment in message.Attachments:
                    attachment.SaveASFile(os.path.join(outputDir, attachment.FileName))
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error when saving the attachment:" + str(e))
except Exception as e:
    print("Error when processing emails messages:" + str(e))

could someone help me understand why this is coming
